# Cell value not showing up in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to read a cell value in an excel with vba. When i try to read it I always get null.

Here is the code snippet

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
i = 3
j = 4

Do While (Len(Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, 16))) <> 0)

    Sheet2.Cells(4, j) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 16)

    j = j + 1
    i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

But the dowhile always gets NULL and comes out of the loop. The cell in sheet1 has value in it.

Please help me out here.

Comment: try to change `Null` into `vbNull`...

Comment: This code has lots of problems. You cannot even execute it; first thing to do is writing it properly. The most typical approach for Null in VBA is Nothing (or vbNull) to be used with "Is". Thus your code should better be: Sheet1.Cells(i,16) Is Not Nothing. Nothing/null is for non-instantiated objects, a cell is always instantiated and thus is never null, can be blank/empty (string value = "") and thus your code does not make any sense (use KekuSemau suggestion better). And this question got a +1?! Well... I am not a down-voter myself unless in extreme-cases, but this surely deserves -1s.

Comment: Agree with @varocarbas on the use of `Nothing` Another way Which is  my fav `If Len(Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i,16).Value)) <> 0 Then` This will ignore spaces pressed by mistake in a cell

Comment: @SiddharthRout I also like quite a lot the Len(Trim(string)), actually this is what I use always (the adapted version, logically) in .NET. In VBA I tend to use IsEmpty, which has always worked fine for me BUT I have got some not-so-good-results when using IsEmpty with .NET and Excel (via Interop); and thus I am starting to not feel 100% comfortable with IsEmpty, even in VBA.

Comment: And one more thing for `IsEmpty`: When I `paste values` to turn formulas into fixed values, some cells can be empty but `isEmpty` is false (they are treated as non-empty with ATL-Cursor-keys). Then _possibly_ `=""` can be better sometimes than `IsEmpty`.

Comment: I had the same problem was returning empty when i tried to extract value from cell, i restarted all excels, went to task manager , Killed Excel. Exe and voila ,it works,

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Do While(Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(i, 16))
```

or maybe then rather

```
Do Until IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(i, 16))
```

Comment: thank you KazJaw and Keku. but when i debug it does not show any value in the cell even if it is there. It is like it is not recognizing sheet1 at all.

Comment: I tried to do a msgbox to show the value of the cell. But it returns a blank.. :(

Comment: I don't understand `does not show value in the cell even if it is there`. Can you explain that again?

Comment: Try `Msgbox Worksheets("Worksheetname").Cells(y, x)`. Note that the row comes first, then the column in `Cells`.

Comment: @user2667222, `Sheet1` is a code name to your sheet which is usually the same as sheet name. But you can try to change it into `Sheets("Sheet1")...` to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Tried renaming the worksheets but did not work. I ran the msgbox and no cell value is showing up.

Comment: Unlikely. Close all excel files, open that one again, select the cell, go to the VB Editor and to the _direct window_ (CTRL-G), and type `?Activecell`.

Comment: Yes. There is something wrong in your code somewhere. You have to post more code examples if you need help with that (and if you do, also note in what module the code is).

Comment: `code`
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
i = 3
j = 4

Do While (Len(Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, 16))) <> 0)
    
    Sheet2.Cells(4, j) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 16)
    
    j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
       
Loop

End Sub
`code`

The command button is in Sheet 1. When I click the command button the data should populate in the second sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are aware, but keep in mind the following difference between IsNull and IsEmpty Excel Help reminds us that:

IsNull --> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether an expression contains no valid data (Null).
IsEmpty --> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether a variable has been initialized.

Okay, this being said, I've fixed your problem of not being able to read the values. I placed the range you are looking at into an array variant. Now the msgbox in the loop will return a value for you.

```
    Sub x()

Dim Arr As Variant
    Arr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 16), Cells(1000, 16)).Value     'You can modify the 1000 by finding the last line, eg - Range.End(xldown).Row

Dim i
    i = 1

Dim CurrentPos
    CurrentPos = Arr(i, 1)

Do Until IsEmpty(Arr(i, 1)) Or IsNull(Arr(i, 1))

    MsgBox CurrentPos

Loop

End Sub
```

What do you guys think?

Comment: Hi.. I am getting a run time error when i run this code..Subscript out of range...

Comment: You are correct. I changed the code. The Arr() was set wrong, since its a 1 dimensional array, not one with 16 columns. My bad, the above code is now fixed. It looks at column P of the worksheet (the one I believe you are using) and checks for values along the way until there is a IsNull or IsEmpty.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Sheet1.Range("P3", Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp)).Copy
    Sheet2.Range("D4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```